# At Synaptic (Debian Wheezy) how to react to message "... broken package ..."?

Tags: debian, synaptic

I have a `synaptoc` problem, with Debian-Wheezy.

```
    uname -a
    Linux primergy 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Trying to apply the installation for `libaudit1` it says:

```
    Could not apply changes!
    Fix broken packages first.*
```

I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and put some further entries (from a similar question) here:

```
    # problem with synaptic 2015-05-21 (from stack-exchange):

    deb http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian jessie main # contrib non-free # 
    #deb-src http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian jessie main # contrib non-free # 
    deb http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main # contrib non-free #
    #deb-src http://ftp.ua.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main # contrib non-free #
```

I just tried it and the error occurs again! no change :)

Aptitude gave:

```
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann# aptitude why libaudit1
   i   adduser Depends passwd (>= 1:4.0.12)  
   p   passwd  Depends libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann# aptitude why-not libaudit1
   Unable to find a reason to remove libaudit1.
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann# aptitude why passwd   
   i   libuuid1 Depends passwd
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann# aptitude why libuuid1
   i   libxapian22 Depends libuuid1 (>= 2.16)
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann# aptitude why adduser 
   i   red5-server Depends adduser (>= 3.11)
   root@primergy:/home/kampmann#
```

Is there any reason I cannot install `libaudit1`

Generally spoken: I wanted to upgrade my system and there are about 1800 such messages!

Secondly, I did the following:

```
root@primergy:/home/kampmann# apt-get install libaudit1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: glib-networking (< 2.33.12) but 2.32.3-1 is to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'skype-debian.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mono' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'skype-debian.old' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mono' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
root@primergy:/home/kampmann#
```

My question: do I have to upgrade Debian Wheezy to the next version?

Answer (score 0):

You comment `contrib` and `non-free` , Use the following sources.list :

First sources rule is :

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Then :

```
apt-get update ; apt-get -f install ; apt-get install libaudit1;
```

Comment: Does that mean that I possibly upgrade to "Jessie" ? - I am not THEE expert in sources.list :)

Comment: Oh sorry , I updated my answer.Howerver if you upgrade to jessie is not bad if you have its circumstances.